# Is there a method to create a sublist from the following list_A with the output as follows in python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, sublist

How to create a sublist from the list as [(INDEX, NUMBER), (INDEX, NUMBER)...]

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
list_A = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
output = [(0,1),(1,2),(3,4),(4,5),(5)]
```

Comment: isn't the output you are looking for: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]?, or why do you leave out (2,3) - what's the formula for your output?

Answer (score 1):

```
list_A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output = [list_A[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(list_A), 2)]
```

You can do also using lambda function

```
import itertools
def grouper(n, it):
    it = iter(it)
    return iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(it, n)), [])
list(grouper(2, list_A))
```

Comment: this is incorrect... you should not skip some values..., the step argument for range is undesireable..

Comment: @adirabargil Then how you compute standard? To split, you must set a parameter.

Comment: read the expected output again...

Answer (score 1):

It's very much doable using list itself:

```
#Original list:
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#How many values would we need to make combination of:
num = 2

li2 = [li[a:a+num] for a in range(len(li))]
print(li2)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9]]
```

If you want to make list of list using 3 values, just change num to 3 and so on. I am pretty sure there will definitely be a numpy function or some other pythonic way to do that same though.